# Lawler's Algorithm Implementation Assistance

Tags: php, algorithm, scheduling

UPDATE2:

I think I got it now:

```
<?php

/*
 * @name Lawler's algorithm PHP implementation
 * @desc This algorithm calculates an optimal schedule of jobs to be
 *       processed on a single machine (in reversed order) while taking
 *       into consideration any precedence constraints.
 * @author Richard Knop
 *
 */

$jobs = array(1 => array('processingTime' => 2,
                         'dueDate'        => 3),
              2 => array('processingTime' => 3,
                         'dueDate'        => 15),
              3 => array('processingTime' => 4,
                         'dueDate'        => 9),
              4 => array('processingTime' => 3,
                         'dueDate'        => 16),
              5 => array('processingTime' => 5,
                         'dueDate'        => 12),
              6 => array('processingTime' => 7,
                         'dueDate'        => 20),
              7 => array('processingTime' => 5,
                         'dueDate'        => 27),
              8 => array('processingTime' => 6,
                         'dueDate'        => 40),
              9 => array('processingTime' => 3,
                         'dueDate'        => 10));
// precedence constrainst, i.e job 2 must be completed before job 5 etc
$successors = array(2=>5,
                    7=>9);
$n = count($jobs);
$optimalSchedule = array();

for ($i = $n; $i >= 1; $i--) {

    // jobs not required to precede any other job
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($jobs as $k => $v) {

        if (false === array_key_exists($k, $successors)) {
            $arr[] = $k;
        }

    }

    // calculate total processing time
    $totalProcessingTime = 0;
    foreach ($jobs as $k => $v) {
        if (true === array_key_exists($k, $arr)) {
            $totalProcessingTime += $v['processingTime'];
        }
    }

    // find the job that will go to the end of the optimal schedule array
    $min = null;
    $x = 0;
    $lastKey = null;
    foreach($arr as $k) {
        $x = $totalProcessingTime - $jobs[$k]['dueDate'];
        if (null === $min || $x < $min) {
            $min = $x;
            $lastKey = $k;
        }
    }

    // add the job to the optimal schedule array
    $optimalSchedule[$lastKey] = $jobs[$lastKey];
    // remove job from the jobs array
    unset($jobs[$lastKey]);
    // remove precedence constraint from the successors array if needed
    if (true === in_array($lastKey, $successors)) {
        foreach ($successors as $k => $v) {
            if ($lastKey === $v) {
                unset($successors[$k]);
            }
        }
    }

}

// reverse the optimal schedule array and preserve keys
$optimalSchedule = array_reverse($optimalSchedule, true);

// add tardiness to the array
$i = 0;
foreach ($optimalSchedule as $k => $v) {
    $optimalSchedule[$k]['tardiness'] = 0;
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($optimalSchedule as $k2 => $v2) {
        if ($j <= $i) {
            $optimalSchedule[$k]['tardiness'] += $v2['processingTime'];
        }
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($optimalSchedule);
echo '</pre>';
```

UPDATE:

So here are some more sources with the explanation of Lawler's algorithm I found:

- [Source 1](http://www.google.com/books?id=aSiBs6PDm9AC&pg=PA166&dq=lawler%27s+algorithm+code&lr=&hl=sk&cd=4#v=onepage&q=&f=false)
- [Source 2](http://www.google.com/books?id=Dw5e12aB7owC&pg=PA360&dq=lawler+algorithm+scheduling&lr=&hl=sk&cd=1#v=onepage&q=lawler%20algorithm%20scheduling&f=false)
- [Source 3](http://www.google.com/books?id=iDtxXdSW5DgC&pg=PA428&dq=lawler%27s+algorithm+code&lr=&hl=sk&cd=119#v=onepage&q=&f=false) (this is a really good source but one crucial page is missing in the preview + this book is not available at amazon or anywhere else bacause it is limited to China - if it were I would have bought it already)

---

Here is my implemenation of Lawler's algorithm in PHP (I know... but I'm used to it):

```
<?php    

$jobs = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$jobsSubset = array(2, 5, 6);
$n = count($jobs);
$processingTimes = array(2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1);
$dueDates = array(3, 15, 9, 7, 11, 20);
$optimalSchedule = array();
foreach ($jobs as $j) {
    $optimalSchedule[] = 0;
}
$dicreasedCardinality = array();
for ($i = $n; $i >= 1; $i--) {

    $x = 0;
    $max = 0;

    // loop through all jobs
    for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {

        // ignore if $j already is in the $dicreasedCardinality array
        if (false === in_array($j, $dicreasedCardinality)) {

            // if the job has no succesor in $jobsSubset
            if (false === isset($jobs[$j+1])
                || false === in_array($jobs[$j+1], $jobsSubset)) {

                // here I find an array index of a job with the maximum due date
                // amongst jobs with no sucessor in $jobsSubset
                if ($x < $dueDates[$j]) {

                    $x = $dueDates[$j];
                    $max = $j;

                }

            }

        }

    }

    // move the job at the end of $optimalSchedule
    $optimalSchedule[$i-1] = $jobs[$max];

    // decrease the cardinality of $jobs
    $dicreasedCardinality[] = $max;
}

print_r($optimalSchedule);
```

Now the above returns an optimal schedule like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 6
)
```

Which doesn't seem right to me. The problem might be with my implementation of the algorithm because I am not sure I understand it correctly. I used [this](http://www.google.com/books?id=aSiBs6PDm9AC&pg=PA166&dq=lawler%27s+algorithm+code&lr=&hl=sk&cd=4#v=onepage&q=&f=false) source to implement it.

The description there is a little confusing. For example, I didn't quite get how is the subset D defined (I guess it is arbitrary).

Could anyone help me out with this? I have been trying to find some sources with simpler explanation of the algorithm but all sources I found were even more complicated (with math proofs and such) so I am stuck with the link above.

Yes, this is a homework, if it wasn't obvious.

I still have few weeks to crack this but I have spent few days already trying to get how exactly this algorithm works with no success so I don't think I will get any brighter during that time.

Comment: And they say everything related to law is offtopic at SO ... ;-)

Comment: Thanks, not that helpful but funny :)

Comment: what does the data in jobsSubset mean?  a slightly real-world explanation is what I am looking for.  is this handling the "no successor" part of the algo?

Comment: Yes, I tried to implement the no successor part of the logic with the $jobsSubset array, the jobs that are already scheduled are there. But it's not working. Basically jobs that need to be scheduled are in $jobs, their deadlines are in $dueDates and the jobs that are already scheduled are in the $jobsSubset. The alg. should return an optimal schedule of all jobs that minimizes the tardiness. I hope that makes sense :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your linked source, Lawler's algorithm takes as input a set of constraints of the form "job `i` must be scheduled before job `j`" (specified as a relation `prec`), which seems not to be featured in your code. If you can schedule the jobs in any order, then Lawler's algorithm specializes to the simpler Earliest Deadline First algorithm (one line description: sort the jobs in order of increasing deadline).

EDIT: let me be more specific. Initially the set `D` is all jobs. Lawler repeatedly finds the job `i` in `D` with the latest deadline, subject to the constraint that no other job `j` in `D` must be scheduled after `i` (i.e., `i` has no successors in `D`), and removes `i` from `D`. The jobs are scheduled in reverse order of removal. If there are no precedence constraints, then this is just EDF.

Comment: The part I don't quite understand is "i has no successors in D". Isn't the only job that has no successor the last job? That's what I initially thought but that would just return array of jobs i reversed order so I added the $jobsSubset array that contains already scheduled jobs. So the job without a successor is either the last job in $jobs or the job that has no successor in $jobsSubset.

Comment: The piece you're missing is that there's another input to Lawler's algorithm that describes which jobs depend on the results of others; for example, if I'm building a house, then I have to dig the foundation before I start on the framing. "Successor" refers to the logical dependencies of the jobs, not when they are scheduled.

Comment: I think I got it right now. I'm going to do some tests and if it works I will accept your answer :) Could you take a look at my updated question just in case you see some more problems there?